# Full Stack Developer?

Tags: job-search, developer

I am an intermediate level .NET developer and had been recently just looking at some job postings on various websites. One thing common I find is companies looking for "Full Stack .NET Developer". What does this mean really? Does it mean a developer who knows every aspect of .NET? And how does one become a full stack developer and how does his CV portray this?

Comment: Specifically, a "Full Stack .NET Developer", at a minimum, probably needs MSSQLServer experience, ASP.NET experience, and C#/VB .NET experience.

Comment: This question is [off-topic](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/2693/custom-off-topic-close-reasons-change/2694#2694). "Questions that address only a specific company **or position** are of limited use to future visitors."

Comment: @DavidK .NET may be specific but it is pretty darn broad.

Comment: In the context of ASP.NET "full stack" developer generally means "must be comfortable and confident with JavaScript, not just server-side code".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Without looking at your specific case, "Full Stack" probably means a developer capable of working from the front end (web pages, javascript, desktop apps) to the back end (windows services, databases). So if you ever implemented for example a complete web application, including back end database and web pages you may qualify as a full stack developer.

Comment: Yeah, Full stack developer is a fairly new buzz word that means you do both front end and back end with at least reasonable proficiency in whatever tech is relevant.

Comment: My current title is SEO Manager, but I also do front and back end web development as well as SEO, conversion optimization and other general Internet Marketing tasks. I know a variety of languages (c# .net, php, coldfusion, jquery). I call myself a Full Stack Developer.

Comment: an I would have said a full stack developer needs to have at least a good understanding of basic networking - strictly a full stack developer is one that can work at layers 1-7 of the OSI stack

Comment: Some good comments by Scott Hanselman https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bx17ywo-5nM

Answer (score -2):

I think it comes from a play on protocol stack of the OSI model.

A developer that has familiarity with all aspects/layers of an application from server to client.

But what are all layers?  To just say .NET Stack means familiar with all possible layers and that is just not reasonable nor required of an intermediate developer unless you are a team of one.

If it is a ASP.NET application then you just need to know ASP.NET and a bit of IIS.  Most likely some MS SQL but there are so many valid data stores now days.

If it is a thick client then WPF, WCF, and a data store.   Does it include MVVM and/or EF?

Does Stack also mean also mean test such as in familiarity with Visual Studio Team System?

Clearly I don't like the word.  There is so much to .NET that a single developer is not going to be familiar with everything .NET.

For a developer position they should call the the technologies specifically.

Now an architect might need to know what all the .NET technologies do but that does not mean they need to be able to code all those technologies.A